# Submit a html form and get html page in c# winapp

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

With the following code, I'm trying to post a html form and expecting a **complete html** page-

```
string reqString = "destination=&calldate_from=2015-08-01&calldate_to=2015-08-02&call_status=ANSWERED&search=Search";

byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString);

HttpWebRequest request =    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.100.70:83/report/outgoing/search");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
request.Host = "192.168.100.70:83";
request.Method = "POST";

Cookie idcookie = new Cookie("PHPSESSID", "19fv94lhgtdr80st6ig366q461") { Domain = "192.168.100.70" };
Cookie bdcookie = new Cookie("ciIPPBXOBd", "nMXEiUJiSU%3D") { Domain = "192.168.100.70" }; 

request.CookieContainer = request.CookieContainer ?? new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(idcookie);
request.CookieContainer.Add(bdcookie);

// Get the request stream.
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
// requestStream.Flush();
requestStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
var res = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription; //gets OK here.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string returnValue = reader.ReadToEnd(); //found empty
reader.Close();
```

Code is running without throwing any exception. But I can not retrieve the full html. How can I do that?

Comment: So `returnValue` doesnt contain html? or is only containing partial html? eg perhaps the stream is only partially sent at the time you call `ReadToEnd`?

Comment: @BugFinder - it's empty.

Comment: Dont suppose its trying to redirect you to the page with the data in?

Comment: This can be due to a whole lot of things, but as BugFinder said, you should check for redirects. If `HttpWebResponse.StatusCode` is `HttpStatusCode.Found`, you should check `HttpWebResponse.Headers["Location"]`, then resolve that relative url using `HttpWebResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri`, and then fetch _that_ page. Either way, checking `HttpWebResponse.StatusCode` should tell you more.